# Round and overwrite xarray data in place

Tags: python, dask, numpy-ndarray, python-xarray

I want to round all of the values in  a xarray to 2 decimal places.

I have tried the following:

```
def round_dim(data_arr):
   data_arr.data = data_arr.data.round(decimals = 2)
   return data_arr
```

I call it as such:

```
data_values = <xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray>
data_values = round_dim(data_values)
```

I would expect `data_values` to now how the same values but rounded to 2 decimal places but this does not happen.

**EDIT**

When I look at the data it is as follows:

```
def round_dim(data_arr):
   #(data_arr.values) is [-50.406578, -50.415337, -50.42315]
   data_arr.data = data_arr.data.round(decimals = 2)
   #(data_arr.values) is [-50.41, -50.42, -50.42]
   return data_arr
```

As can be seen after `data_arr.data = data_arr.data.round(decimals = 2)` I do get the correct rounding.

However, doing:

```
data_values = <xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray>
data_values = round_dim(data_values)

print(data_values.values)
```

I do not get the correct rounded values, instead:

```
[-50.409999, -50.419998, -50.419998]
```

I would expect the data array to look like `[-50.41, -50.42, -50.42]`

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproductible example? I don't know how you create the data initially.

Comment: hey, I figured out the issue. Posted my answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was to do with the `dtype` of the data. Apparently `dtype` of `float32` does not do well with `.round`.

To fix the issue, I converted the data to `dtype` `float64` using `.astype('float64')` and the rounding works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply `round(decimals = 2)` to your whole dataset, you can use [`xarray.Dataset.map`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.map.html#xarray.Dataset.map).

It returns a **copy** of the original dataset with all its data rounded, it does not work in place.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray

dataset = xarray.Dataset()
dataset["a"] = xarray.DataArray(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
dataset["b"] = xarray.DataArray(np.arange(10))
print(dataset)
# <xarray.Dataset>
# ...
#    a        (dim_0) float64 0.0 0.1111 0.2222 0.3333 ... 0.7778 0.8889 1.0
#    b        (dim_0) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

def round_dim(dataset):
    return dataset.map(lambda a: np.round(a, decimals=2))

dataset = round_dim(dataset)
print(dataset)
# <xarray.Dataset>
# ...
#     a        (dim_0) float64 0.0 0.11 0.22 0.33 0.44 0.56 0.67 0.78 0.89 1.0
#     b        (dim_0) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: this returns only the data array back, not the data array imbedded in the xarray. for example, I cannot call `.data` on `data_values` after I round it. To fix that I just did `data_values.data = round_dim(data_values)` However, this still does not round the majority of values to 2 decimal places. I see the following: `[-62.740001678989, -62.75, -62.75, -62.7521368636]` I believe there is rounding actually taking place (as the 2 `-62.75` values suggest) but the trailing numbers are still there, it does not completely round to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Oh ok, you want to apply the rounding to the whole dataset. Ok. I'll edit my answer with `.map`.

Comment: the problem is more so the extra digits. The rounding works but the extra digits beyond the first 2 after the decimal remain. Not sure how to get rid of those. so that only 2 digits after the decimal remain.

Comment: I added more information with the edit to the question